# Reactで発見した波括弧を使う代入文がどのように動作するのかわからない

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const {id} = this.props.match.params
```

react入門者です
変数代入について
このコードの結果はわかるのですが、どのように処理されて結果
idという変数にpropsのidを拾ってきて代入しているのかわからないです
reactの機能ですか？
reduxでしょうか？